# Listing Latest Blog Post in a Block

Tags: blocks, nodes

This is my first time using Drupal so I'm not entirely sure if I'm asking the right questions. I come from a WordPress background so I may be approaching this problem in the wrong manner.

I'm attempting to create a list of the latest blog post in a block that I created. How would I go about doing something like this? Would I list it via PHP within the block editor or is there some type of module (?) that I should be using? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: follow this series of tutorial, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3L9JLZOb_LQ

Comment: Thanks shrish. I appreciate your pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a block view of nodes (of whatever type you are calling a post). You actually create the block in [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views). Views are one of the things that separates Drupal from WordPress. If you have no idea what they are, check out [this page](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/views).

Comment: Thanks ontoligent, I'll look into that and report back. Thanks for your assistance.